# How to add an extra parameter to the img source in HTML using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a situation where I need to differentiate two calls by the path in the source of a HTML. This is how the img tag looks like

```
<img src="/folder/12280218/160024536.images.jpg" />
```

I am planning to alter the source to

```
<img src="/folder/12280218/160024536.images.jpg/1" />
```

**observe the "/1" at the end of src**

I need this so that I can change the flow in the controller when I am serving this image.

This is what I have tried until now.

```
my $string = '<p><img src="/folder/12280218/160024536.images.jpg" /></p>';

$string =~ s/<img\s+src\=\"(.*)"\s+\/><\/p>/<img src\=\"$1\/1" \><\/p>/g;
```

This is working as long as the `$string` looks like this.
In our application, user has the ability to alter the HTML input using CKEditor. 
He can alter the image tag by adding `width="800"` before or after the src attribute. I want the regular expression to handle all these situations.

Please let me know how to proceed. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use an HTML Parser instead of regex

Comment: I think it would be better to add a query parameter `/folder/12280218/160024536.images.jpg?mode=2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace :
`(<img.*src="[^"]*)(".*\/>)`
by
`$1/1$2`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fAE2aK/2)
**Edit :** Changed the regex to handle situations with other attributes (like the "width" part)

Comment: if you have two `img` tags in a row your regexp is going to remove one.

Comment: In the demo, I actually have 3 img tags in a row